# gl_FrontFacing - is there perfomance cost?

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

If I use `gl_FrontFacing` in my PS, is there any performance cost during vertex transformation (like cross product from triangle  vertices), or is this value computed any time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard answer is **profile**. It may vary between platforms, vendors, driver versions etc.

I would note that if you use this, you are clearly not backface culling, and so will lose some performance there. This information is always computed as part of the fixed function hardware rasterization stage (as usually backface culling is enabled), so barring any costs to transmit this value to the shader, it should have no performance impact.

Comment: I need to have turn off culling, because I am rendering grass and using double-sided polygong

Comment: I mentioned that because if you try to profile and don't take such things into account, it can be very easy to get misleading results. Obviously you need to turn off culling to get double sided rendering.

Comment: Yes.. so profiling is useless. I only needed to know, if gl_FrontFacing is auto-calculated everytime or only if I read it in shader

Comment: Profiling is most decidedly *not* useless. There could be non-negligible cost of getting this data out of the fixed function pipeline and into the shader. (There probably isn't, but you never know) Interpolators are surprisingly expensive, and this is something similar.

Comment: In this case, profiling really is useless. The rasterizer absolutely has to know whether it is dealing with a front- or back-facing primitive. Whether or not you use the value of `gl_FrontFacing` in your fragment shader is not going to change the fact that it has to do winding determination before the fragment shader even runs. This is one of those things that GL generates for you and you can use free-of-cost. Take a look [here](http://www.g-truc.net/doc/OpenGL%204.4%20Pipeline%20Map.pdf), the 4th subsystem down (*Rasterization*) (under 14.6.1). You cannot short-circuit facing determination.

Comment: The cost is not the calculation, as I said. It would be in making this available to the fragment shader. Modern GPU architectures are very generic: I would not be surprised if referencing this value, which isn't used as much, results in another load from memory or larger FIFO utilization. Then again, it could not. Profiling, however, *will* tell you.

Answer (score 2):

I feel obligated to point out that there are too many things the rasterizer needs to know the facing of the polygon it is drawing for your use or non-use of `gl_FrontFacing` in the fragment shader to have any affect on the operation of the pipeline.

I highly suggest you take a look at the [PDF diagram here](http://www.g-truc.net/doc/OpenGL%204.4%20Pipeline%20Map.pdf), which shows all of the stages and inputs/outputs for the OpenGL graphics pipeline.

If you look carefully at the rasterizer part of the diagram, you will see that polygons must always first go through facing determination. This is used for polygon mode, culling, stencil testing, and in older versions of GL, lighting.

Keep in mind no cross-product is necessary to determine whether a polygon is front or back-facing (GL does not compute or use a triangle normal for this process). OpenGL actually uses the polygon's winding (after projection) and compares it with the front-face you established (Clockwise or Counter-Clockwise). This is a far simpler process than you expected, and it only has to be done once per-primitive, since all polygons in OpenGL are planar.